# Solspace Ratings Pagination Links Variable Pair

Tags: solspace, module

I read in the old solspace forums that the the rating module would support the ee variable pairs
{pagination_links}
{/pagination_links}

But when i add them ton the template only the tag {pagination_links} renders.

Do you know if its supported?

I am using the latest version of ee and the ratings module

Thanks

```
{exp:rating:entries collection="Apartment Reviews" limit="10" orderby="rating_date" sort="desc" paginate="bottom"}
    {rating_paginate}
        <div class="paging x">
            {pagination_links}
                {page}
                    <ul>
                        {previous_page}
                            <li class="prev"><a href="{pagination_url}">&laquo;</a></li>
                        {/previous_page}

                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>        

                        {next_page}
                            <li class="next"><a href="{pagination_url}">&raquo;</a></li>
                        {/next_page}
                {/page}

                </ul>
            {/pagination_links}                             
        </div>  
    {/rating_paginate}
{/exp:rating:entries}
```

Comment: There's a bug on your code. The `ul` opening and closing tags are in different nesting levels.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Solspace did not update the pagination class used on Ratings. The same thing happened some time ago with Calendar. The EECMS updated the pagination class, but Calendar was using the CodeIgniter pagination class.

Please, check if you're using the last versions of Rating and EECMS. If you are, contact Solspace and report the issue as a bug.

Comment: Thanks There was an archived post in the old forums from 2012 saying that they working on implementing this.
Frustrating as my pagination for ratings will be different to my pagination for channel entries.
Is it possible with ratings pagination to replicate this pagiantion?
{pagination_links}
<ul>{previous_page}
<li class="prev"><a href="{pagination_url}">&laquo;</a></li>
{/previous_page}
{page}
<li><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
{/page}
{next_page}
<li class="next"><a href="{pagination_url}">&raquo;</a></li>
{/next_page}
</ul>
{/pagination_links}

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how. I had to change all the pagination links across a website because of this issue with Calendar. I suggest you to write to them.